# Matching screen corners in Win 10

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

I am using two displays on my PC:

- one 27 inch, 2560 x 1440 resultion display with scaling set to 125%
- one 27 inch, 3840 x 2160 resolution display with scaling set to 175%.

The scaling is set so that all windows roughly retain their size when moved between the two displays.

Unfortunately, Windows 10 is not taking the scaling into account when arranging the displays.

[image]

When I drag the cursor from the top-right corner of display 2 (the WQHD one) to the other screen, it appears in the middle of the screen. (Of course I could also line up the top edges of the two screens, which would give me the same problem on the bottom.)

I would like the corners of the screens to match to enable a seamless transition of the cursor from one screen to the other.
Does anybody know any way to do this?

Comment: This question crops up a lot, in many guises & I can't find a canonical one right now, but essentially Windows can only see the image you provided, it cannot see the result of your view-scaling & therefore has no idea how the physical screens map to you visually.